# Open Notification Settings only for "Group"

Tags: android

With notification channels, you can send the user to the app's notification prefs very simply with ->

```
val notifyIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
            notifyIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context?.packageName)
            startActivity(notifyIntent)
```

You can also send the user to the settings for a specific channel just by adding an extra to the intent ->

```
val notifyIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
            notifyIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_CHANNEL_ID, "myChannelId")
            notifyIntent.putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, context?.packageName)
            startActivity(notifyIntent)
```

**My Question:**

Is there a way to send the user to the settings for a specific **group**?

I have 3 groups in notification settings -> News, Weather, and Sports.  Each group has 3 or more channels.  I'd like to send the user to the notification settings for ONLY weather if possible

thank you!